# Javascript callback - how to return the result?

Tags: javascript, callback

I am struggling to totally understand callbacks and i am stumbling at the final hurdle.

Within JS I am calling a function which then calls a PHP function using a dojo rpc Json Service. I have stepped through the function in firebug and the PHP is executing and returning me the correct response via the callback but I don’t know how to return the value to the initial JS variable that invoked the JS function? E.g.

```
JS Function 1

Function one(){

Var test = getPhp(number);

}

function getPhp(number)
{

this.serviceBroker = new dojo.rpc.JsonService(baseUrl + '/index/json-rpc/');

    var result = serviceBroker.phpFunc(number);

    result.addCallback(
        function (response)
        {
            if (response.result == 'success')
            {
                return response.description;
               //I am trying to pass this value back to the 
               //var test value in   function one

            }
        }
    );
}
```

Basically i now need to pass response.description back to my var test variable in function one.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Ok will do.
There must be a way of executing php through JS though and returning that value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible, since the callback is run asynchronously. This means that the getPhp function returns before the callback is executed (this is the definition of a callback, and one of the reasons asynchronous programming is hard ;-) ).

What you want to do is create a new method that uses the `test` variable. You need to call this method when the callback is executed.

i.e.

```
function one(result) {
  var test = result;
  // Do anything you like
}

function getPhp(number, callback) {
  this.serviceBroker = new dojo.rpc.JsonService(baseUrl + '/index/json-rpc/');
  result.addCallback(
    function (response)
    {
        if (response.result == 'success')
        {
           callback(response.description);
        }
    }
  );
}

getPhp(number, function(result) { one(result); });
```

This last method creates an 'anonymous function' that is passed to the getPhp function. This function gets executed at the time the response arrives. This way you can pass data to the `one(number)` function **after** the data arrives.

Comment: Hi Kamiel thanks for your solution. Should this line go underneath result.addCallback(

var result = serviceBroker.getPhp(number,callback);

Comment: You add the callback as a parameter to the `getPhp` function, and call it when you get the 'success' result. This way you can tell the `getPhp` function what to do when the data arrives, but in a asynchronous way.

Comment: What if you call directly `one(response.description);` instead of `callback(response.description);` ?

Comment: @FlorianCourtial you could, but that would tie the implementation of `getPhp` and `one` directly together. It's considered good practise, especially when testing code, to make that the responsibility of the caller. This way you could make `getPhp` do different things depending on the `callback` you pass in.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that you can't.

Do whatever you want to do with the data in the callback or functions you call from the callback. You can't return anything from it.

Comment: You could also pass in a function as a parameter to getPhp and have that function do something (e.g. set a property) with the callback result.

Comment: If you are going to return the data to a function what makes the widget spin, then move the code that makes the widget spin to the callback function.

Answer (score 3):

A much cleaner answer:

```
getPhp(number);

function one(data){
    var test = data;
    // do what you want
}

function getPhp(number)
{

    this.serviceBroker = new dojo.rpc.JsonService(baseUrl + '/index/json-rpc/');

    var result = serviceBroker.phpFunc(number);

    result.addCallback(
        function (response)
        {
            if (response.result == 'success')
            {
                one(response.description);
            }
        }
    );
}
```