# javascript function with $.get won't return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following function:

```
function parseLink(link){
 var newlink="";

 $.get(link,
   function(data){    

   startoffset = data.indexOf("location.replace") + 18;
   endoffset = data.indexOf("tiny_fold = 1;") - 8;
   newlink= data.substr(startoffset,(endoffset-startoffset));


});

return newlink;

 }
```

I'm using jquery $.get to parse a URL, which works fine if I do it without a function, but the function will return the empty string. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what; any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you requesting a URL from another domain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript callback - how to return the result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453295/javascript-callback-how-to-return-the-result)

Comment: no, is from the same domain the URL will be sent to my backend to generate a security key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pass in a function to be called when `$.get` returns.  Something like:

```
function parseLink(link, callback) {
   $.get(link,
      function(data) {
         startoffset = data.indexOf("location.replace") + 18;
         endoffset = data.indexOf("tiny_fold = 1;") - 8;
         var newlink= data.substr(startoffset,(endoffset-startoffset));
         callback(newlink);
      });
 }
```

Then you can call it with:

```
parseLink('foo', function (newlink)
  {
     //Stuff that happens with return value
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

The call to $.get is asynchronous. See the control flow is like this:

```
parseUrl("http://www.test.com")
$.get(..., function callback() { /* this is called asynchronously */ })
return "";
... 
// sometime later the call to $.get will return, manipulate the
// newLink, but the call to parseUrl is long gone before this
callback();
```

I think what you meant to do is:

```
function parseUrl(link, whenDone) {
    $.get(link, function () {
        var newLink = "";
        // Do your stuff ...
        // then instead of return we´re calling the continuation *whenDone*
        whenDone(newLink);
    });
}

// Call it like this:
parseUrl("mylink.com", function (manipulatedLink) { /* ... what I want to do next ... */ });
```

Welcome to async spaghetti world :)

Comment: Oh by the way ... since you´re using jQuery anyway, you might have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ . If you get your head around it it´s a bit easier (more linear) to read/write I think ...

Answer (score 0):

Because the `.get()` operates asynchronously, `parseLink()` carries on executing and returns the empty `newlink` before the AJAX call has returned.

You'll need to trigger whatever is working with `newlink` from the callback, which may need you to rethink your implementation a little. What comes next (what should then happen to the populated `newlink`)?